# What is the most commonly-used version control system with support to tagging/labeling?

Tags: version-control, label, tags, branch

Actually I'm using VSS, but I was wondering if there is another tool for version control with support for labels/tags (the subversion implementation doesn't count:). What are you guys using?

Comment: Why doesn't subversion's implementation of labels and tags not count?

Comment: Subversion just uses copies to implement tags/branches, which may not always meet everybody's requirements.

Comment: Subversion has only versioned tree copies, no tags or branches.

Comment: Thanks WaffleMatt and ndim, that's the reason why.

Answer (score 2):

Git supports tag and I use them all the time

[Link to *git book* section on tag](http://book.git-scm.com/3_git_tag.html)